# Why is this transparent image showing up with a white background on a device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I am creating a transparent image on iOS using Quartz. However, this image shows up with the proper transparency in the Simulator, but shows a white background on a device.

Here is the code I'm using for this:

```
+ (UIImage *)clearRect:(CGRect)rect inImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([image size], NO, 0.0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([image size]);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [image size].width, [image size].height)];
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation(result);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

This is what I'm seeing on the device:

[image: White image instead of transparent]

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I pasted your code, inserted one of the image in resources, run it on iPad 2, saved it to documents as png and opened it in PS. It was transparent. It would seem you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: its showing transparent in simulator.. but not showing in device.. BTW Thanks..

Comment: I tested the methode you posted on device. It works fine. There must be a problem in the way you are presenting it. So as for the question "How to create transparent image in iOS", the answer is already the code you posted. What is your presenting result in your application on device? What do you see or not see that you do in simulator?

Comment: Matic Oblak.. can u send me your Demo project .. my mail id is manimodi@gmail.com thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the code works in the simulator and not your device you may have become victim to the cruftmonster described below:

http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/642-beware-the-cruftmonster/

You may have some legacy files that have been removed from your Xcode project but not the application bundle on the device. Did you initially test with opaque images?

Not sure if this is the solution, but it certainly matches the symptoms you describe.

Comment: I am installing new and fresh code in device.. recent was deleted.. but same problem.. but thanks friend..